# Login from one Client A creates default cookies in Client B

Tags: single-sign-on, openid, identityserver4

I am using `IdentityServer4` as my authorization server, and I have 2 clients(A and B). When I login from **Client A** successfully, cookie is also created on **Client B**. The cookie on **Client B** happens without redirection. Its great to have it btw. But the problem is I want to have few of client's own claims on the cookies. As it doesn't goes through `Notification->SecurityTokenValidated` endpoint, I cannot use custom claims for the Client B. Same happens for **Client A**, if I login from **Client B**.

I need to know how this cookie on Client B is being created and how can I add my own claims on it?

**Updated Details:**
The behavior i know of OpenId connect is to request authorization from Auth Server(identityserver) in case the request needs Authorization. In my case, I have anonymous page in **client B** which I refresh after login in **Client A**, and still get the auth cookies in **client B** without any redirection to Auth server.

```
Client Config for Client A

{
    "ClientId": "nolib.client",
    "ClientName": "Web Form Test",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "implicit" ],
    "ClientSecrets": [
      {
        "Value": "2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b"
      }
    ],
    "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:11716/account/signInCallback" ],


    "RequireClientSecret": false,

    "AllowedScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "api1"
    ],
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true,
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true
  }

Client B
  {
    "ClientId": "81117971101161171097797112115",
    "ClientName": "MVC client",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "hybrid" ],
    "ClientSecrets": [
      {
        "Value": "2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b"
      }
    ],
    "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:6006/signin-oidc" ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:6006/signout-callback-oidc" ],

    "RequireClientSecret": false,

    "AllowedScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "api1"
    ],
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true,
    "RequireConsent": true,
    "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true
  }
```

**Update 2**

With few more test I find that, these Cookies I get in Client B are same as  Client A created. Similarly if I login from Client B then client A gets the same Cookies from B. Could this be because i am in Localhost? However I do have different ports. Additionally, there is no other link between Client A to B than from the Auth Server.

Comment: try giving name to your cookies from cookie middleware in both the clients, it will make sure if you are seeing the same cookie or different one.

Comment: I am seeing same cookies. If i add custom claim in 1 client then it appears on another.

Comment: check my updated answer - are you seeing the same set of cookies?

Answer (score 2):

Identity server comes with Single sign on , means if user is logged in once on Client A and then goes to Client B it doesn't need to re-login. But every client has to authenticate itself which it does through back channel if it validates the cookies. And then it creates the cookies as well for the second client. This is the behavior that you are seeing.

Not sure why you cannot add separate cookies for different clients. As client specific cookies are not shared. You can add claims in your client configuration for for Client A and different claims for Client B. Identity server will honor your configuration!

**Update**  - this image clearly shows different cookies for different clients - "lmClient" is client A and "mvchybrid" is client B

[image]

Keep in mind its localhost and if you open another tab on the browser with same domain - localhost - you will see the same cookie. these are not new cookies. And in your comments you have said that if you don't put Authorize attribute you still get cookies, means that its not going to identity server and most likely you are seeing the same cookies created for client A not new ones.

As I said try to give name to your cookie in the middleware, just like i did it will give you the idea if you are seeing the same cookies

You can set it up like this in your client startup class -

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {

                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
                CookieName = "mvchybrid",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = false,
                Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                    // validates with each http request
                    OnValidatePrincipal = ValidatePrincipal
                }
            });
```

Comment: That's correct. But as far as I knew, this behavior only occurred in Authorized request. My issue right now is that, i dont even need to have authorized request to get the cookies. I refresh my anonymous page and i already have the cookies.

Comment: have you set the CookieAuthentication option AutomaticAuthenticate to true on your client ?

Comment: No i haven't. I have updated client config on my question.

Comment: Hmm, so this problem will not exists if i use separate domains? I would also like to see your cookie middleware. Thanks